# Is there an easy way to access the webcam from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, webcam

How can I access the webcam easily with VS2010 and C#?

I tried to copy the avicap21.dll, but VS2010 can't import the library.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a native DLL. not a COM object so VS will not import it for you. You need to write your own "header" translation or find something on the web:

(this is a translation for a later version)
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/810262008070218AM/8.aspx

Also you should consider using DirectShow which is a more .NET friendly way to access WebCams.

E.

Answer (score 0):

Use WPF.

```
     <Grid>
        <MediaElement Source="rtsp://127.0.0.1/cam"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [WIA libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provide an easy way to pull still images from a scanner or webcam. They also allow scanners to push images to your windows box.